# Editing JS in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i'm using template for wordpress , i need to add a small function
i want the focus go automatically to the next field after choosing the pick up date
[image]

[image]

i've already entered the theme editor but i cant find the js code
i found the code i want in inspect element terminal , but i want to know how to edit those codes
[image]
how can i find the js files that controls this form ?

Comment: Add tab indexes to the fields. It will help with accessibility and make your forms more user friendly. Also, I don't think users need you to change fields for them automatically. That isn't a very common user experience.